# SPOJ Swift - NZEC

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I have problem with SPOJ,
in all of my solution I had NZEC problem. I have read that is problem (non-zero exit code).

SPOJ link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/

And my code below:

```
for i in 1...100000{
    let number = Int(readLine()!)!

    if number != 42{
        print(number)
    }
    else
    {
        break
    }
}
```

PS: In Xcode I have created command line project and in console I have information: Program ended with exit code: 0

That problem is in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to exit after the number 42:

```
for i in 1...100
{
    let number = Int(readLine()!)!

    if number != 42
    {
        print(number)
    }
    else
    {
        continue
    }
}
```

but in this case, the else section is useless! I don't really understand the problem. Sorry, If it's my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way of handling IO in the Spoj's [TEST](http://spoj.com/problems/TEST) problem in Swift:

```
while let input = readLine(), Int(input) != 42 {
    if !input.isEmpty {
       print(input)
    } else {
       print("Input cannot be empty")
       continue
    }
}
```

It reads IO data until there is **something to read** OR the number **42 appears** in the input data.

This example is available as an example code for the Swift language on Ideone: http://ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_85. You can also see this code in action here: http://ideone.com/lH6iZS.